# How to test android app in Galaxy S4 configuration using emulator?

Tags: android, galaxy

I need to test my app in Galaxy S4. But I have no real device so I want to test my app in emulator. What will be the configuration needed to do this in emulator?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

See this and you can increase the RAM size if your Machine can handle that.

Comment: How do you handle the system bar at bottom in emulator as S4 doesn't have a system bar in it. As per your config resolution takes 1080*1824 but it needs to  be 1080*1920..

Comment: I've created the same simulator but I couldn't run the simulator.. its taking too much time and then just timeout

Comment: @VishalKhakhkhar what PC configuration are you running on?

Comment: My PC configuration is Core i5 2.5 GHz and 8GB RAM 64Bit Windows 8

Comment: To remove the system bar at the bottom, set "Buttons" to "Hardware" instead of "Software".

Comment: I tried to test an app with the same configuration Virtual machine except with 1gig RAM - wasn't able - it showed only a black screen and that was it.
My computer supports FullHD and it is on a 64bit Linux - Any sugestions?

Comment: Became white screen and closed after some giving closing warnign

Comment: where do you from download this emulator? can you give me a link to download this emulator for S4? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should choose "Use Host GPU" option in Emulator options.

Comment: I did the above and set **VM Heap** to 32 (instead of 64).  Then I set the internal HD to 800 MB (from 200).  It finally started up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mac the GPU makes it start but is very slow and the App icons come all compressed the messages boxes are reversed(as you'd see on a mirror).

Sansung has an on-line RemoteTestLab, that does not work either only once it popped but then it blew and never fires again.