# How to run an emulator using Galaxy S4 configuration?

Tags: android, galaxy

I have created an galaxy s4 emulator using this post [how to open galaxy S4 emulator](http://www.entrycoder.com/2013/09/how-to-open-galaxy-s4-configured.html)
but my problem is when I tried to run this emulator it takes very long time and at last it said time is out. My ram is 6GM. And I created emulator by providing 800MB ram. And my laptop screen resolution is HD. 
How to resolve my problem immediately because I have to test my app in galaxy s4.

Comment: no, I have not that's why I am trying to run my app in Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulators are slow. No matter what configuration you have. So testing in emulator doesn't mean it'll give you same behaviour in the real device.

Unless samsung decided to do so, it won't be available with Android SDK as predefined config. You may need to manually set the configurations (which is what you have done). Even then the OS gonna run in S4 is customised by Samsung yet again as I said earlier you won't get it with your SDK package.

Comment: I tried to run my emulator with salaxy s4 configuration. It's not my problem but my problem is why it's takes long time and then it said time is out. How to get rid of this solution.

Comment: Try deleting and creating new AVD

Answer (score 2):

I got it working with the settings the other link holds ([How to test android app in Galaxy S4 configuration using emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646398/how-to-test-android-app-in-galaxy-s4-configuration-using-emulator)) and "Target Google APIs (Google Inc.) - API Level 17" and also I let the Emulator help by my GPU "Emulator Options: Use Host GPU".

Hope you folks get it working to :)

Comment: Finally successfully make emulator running & on!!!check out here ==> http://d.pr/i/6DpC

Comment: @Robert please can you help me out in solvng my problem my S4 emulator is not running it takes long time to run and shows constatnly black screen

Comment: @User42590 I recommend you to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/). After signing up, there're lots of pre-defined emulators for download. Samsung S4 included. Hope this helps. Don't waste your precious time on Google's Android emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung has not released Add-on for galaxy s4.

But we have an alternatives for the Same Configurations.

Actual:Samsung S4 (1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density))

Alternative:Sony Xperia Z (1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density))

Both are using Drawable-xxhdpi resource folder.

To configure Sony Xperia Z:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Testing on Sony Xperia Z emulator,will effect the same result in Samsung galaxy s4.

Comment: Our app looks different from Samsung's remote Lab S4 vs the Sony Xperia Z add-on. However in the Eclipse graphic layout it looks (I assume) correct (ie like the Samsung remote lab).  Don't know why.

Comment: May be the problem related to Sony Xperia Z (441 ppi density)