# Android Galaxy S4 Emulator Not Opening

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

I've created simulator for S4 as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16646536/206809.

My PC configuration is Core i5 2.5 GHz and 8GB RAM 64Bit Windows 8 still I'm unable to load the emulator. Are you able to run the same ? Please suggest if I'll require higher config. Attached my Emulator Config for reference
[image: S4 configuration]

When I'm running same it stuck in this screen for a long and then time out.
[image: Stuck in Loading]

Comment: Check "Use host GPU" and try again, make sure while opening the emulator the dialog window shows HAXM is workin

Comment: Did you tried with Use host GPU?

Comment: Yes and cause of it simulator started but its too much flickering and then screen is blank..

Comment: I have almost the same specs you got. The screen flickering and blank issue also occurs for me.(Emulator: s4 and HTC one)

Comment: The avd still needs the be stable on higher Api and resolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tick "Use Host GPU" and try. Some times it may work.
Not sure.

Comment: Yes and cause of it simulator started but its too much flickering and then screen is blank..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

I have opened successfully s4 emulator and it's working fine. I think you should reduce size of RAM, Internal storage, and sdcard of emulator according to your computer RAM example I have 4 GB ram in my pc and I have changed according to it like :

```
 RAM : 512,
 Internal Storage : 128,
 Sdcard : 256.
```

and

also reduce screen size of your emulator(in my case I have used 5) should be 5 to 7. More Screen size of emulator takes more time to open.

so according to my knowledge size should be your issue.

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Emulators have been driving me crazy for long time because they are so slow. I had no problems
using emulators on android 2.3, 2.2 etc. It takes for ever to load an emulator for android 4.0 and above and most for the time it won't even load. The high resolution you try to you use, the less chance for emulator to start.

I run my emulators on windows 7. Anyway, after a long search, i came a cross this link. http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html.

Thanks to intel VM Acceleration for windows. Emulators runs on my laptop in seconds. Its not perfect yet but it does the job. I thought i'd share this, because i wished i knew about it long time ago.

Note: CPU must support one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:

Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)

and if it does support VT, remember to enable  VT .